# How can I set up port forwarding for SQL Server 2005?

Tags: networking, sql-server, port-forwarding

Subject :how to use port forwarding

Internet------> Router in my network ------->LocalMachine (Windows
2003) -->Sqlserver2005

How can I access SQL Server through the internet via a router in the local network?

My router IP Address is =192.168.1.86; 
My local machine which is connected to the router Ip Address is=

192.168.1.81
At port No=1433

tell me how to use port forwarding 
Thanks for help in advance

Comment: Manish - please continue to use THIS post for help on this problem.  Do not continue to post additional duplicate questions.  It's ok to edit this post as needed, instead.

Answer (score 3):

This really depends what router you are using. You appear to have the idea of port forwarding reasonably correct, and most of the info you need to hand.

5 minutes with the manual of your router should get you there - if you let us know the model, someone may be able to give accurate pointers.

Additionally, if you plan to forward SQL server transactions, might I suggest you use a VPN? Marginally harder to set up, but more secure. At the very least, ensure whatever you forward is encrypted, and try to lock down which IPs can access your forwarded port wherever possible.

Comment: +1 for VPN suggestion - opening port 1433 to the 'net is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to really, really think about what you are doing. Perhaps you should google the term " SQL Slammer Worm " before you just open up your SQL server to the mean nasty internets.

Yes, this has been patched long ago, but it's a very big indicator of what *can* and *did* happen.

If you need remote access to SQL, I would ONLY do this over a VPN. Period.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it many ways:

-just forward the remote desktop port from the public interface of you router to the local ip of you windows box

```
ROUTER_EXT_IP: 3389 -> 192.168.1.81: 3389
```

-you can just forward the SQL Server 2005 port, the default TCP port that SQL Server uses is 1433

```
ROUTER_EXT_IP: 1433 -> 192.168.1.81: 3389: 1433
```

After that you specify your external ip in your application and that is it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on every model of router, basically, you need to specify, for a given port to which server the requests should be redirect to.

Do not forget to setup a static ip for this server.
And have a nice firewall setup, expose a critical server like this is risky.
Why do u need a direct access ? if it is for a connection, the secure way remains a VPN tunnel between the two sites.